# read line by line a csv file in R and create a feature?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, dataset

i have stored the interpolated data to a csv file with 181 rows, where each row has it's first element represented by the label and the rest is a time series data, for ex in this format:

1st row : 0, 980, 888, 720,987,543

2nd row : 0, 880, 999, 820,990,888, 980, 898, 780,987

3rd row : 1, 945, 856, 767,745,883

4th row : 2, 780, 899, 920,890,988, 780, 998, 870,787

5th row : 2, 800, 900, 822,999,880, 988, 899

and so on for the rest of the 181 rows, where the labels are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. Also, notice i have different lengths for each row.
I want to create features,(by applying lets say, mean() is one of the features) using the time series only i.e, "980, 888, 720,987,543" and excluding the "label y" i.e, the 0, and i want to do that for each row and create a data frame that has 33 features plus the label, like:

```
dim(labl_feat_df)[1] # 181 rows
dim(labl_feat_df)[2] # 34 columns (33 features and the label)
```

so the labl_feat_df will look like:

```
     label  mean(TS)  SD(TS) ........ feat33
1     0
2     0
.
.
.
181   6
```

where mean(TS) and sd(TS) are the 1st and 2nd feature.

So my questions are: how can i read a file with different length? and if it should be line by line, how possible and efficient to create those 33 feature and add them to the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Using `Lines` in the Note at the end, read it in, add a row number, `id`, and reshape from wide to long.  Drop NA rows and summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF <- read.table(text =Lines, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE, fill = NA)
DF %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(V1, id)) %>%
  drop_na %>%
  group_by(V1, id) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     V1    id  mean    sd
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1  824. 190. 
2     0     2  914.  80.3
3     1     3  839.  82.9
4     2     4  879.  84.0
5     2     5  898.  75.3
```

**2) Base R** Using `DF` from (1) reshape to long form using `reshape`, remove NAs using `na.omit` and `aggregate`:

```
DF2 <- na.omit(reshape(DF, dir = "long", varying = list(2:ncol(DF))))
aggregate(V2 ~ V1 + id, DF2, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

giving:

```
  V1 id   V2.mean     V2.sd
1  0  1 823.60000 190.24800
2  0  2 913.55556  80.28404
3  1  3 839.20000  82.88667
4  2  4 879.11111  83.95750
5  2  5 898.28571  75.28770
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
0, 980, 888, 720,987,543
0, 880, 999, 820,990,888, 980, 898, 780,987
1, 945, 856, 767,745,883
2, 780, 899, 920,890,988, 780, 998, 870,787
2, 800, 900, 822,999,880, 988, 899"
```

Comment: That was just to keep it self contained and reproducible.  You would use `read.table("MyData.csv", ...etc...)` assuming it is in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple base R solution:

```
#read file line by line
textfile<-read.table("soquestion.txt", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)

#find statistics
mean_TS<-rowMeans(textfile[, 2:ncol(textfile)], na.rm=TRUE)
SD_TS <- apply(textfile[, 2:ncol(textfile)], 1, function(x) {sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)})

answer<-cbind(label=textfile[,1], mean_TS, SD_TS, textfile[,-1])
```